# Something wrong with my understanding in subnetting

Tags: subnet

I did "ipconfig" at my computer, and its gave me this thing:

> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.100.102.8
>
> Subnet Mask . .. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Is any reason in here? from what I learned - if "10" in the first octet, thats means this ip is class A. But in the subnet mask the "ipconfig" gave me, its like the "10" pointing to class C. If someone can explain me this.

Comment: Probably best to post this on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`10.x.x.x` is just something that can be reused locally-- it's not routable. Call it "class A" if you want, but that terminology is confusing in this context.

The mask is what splits the network from the hosts. When you have networks under networks, you have sub-networks, or subnets. The subnet mask (often called simply "mask") is what tells you what part of an address is network and what part isn't.

This example doesn't even require going to binary (and the class-A,B,C terminology is only confusing here): `10.100.102.x` is your network and `8` is your host.

Listen to and obey the subnet mask.

Comment: Wait a minute! if for example I have this IP : __155 . 115 . 51 . 68 / 29__ so I can know that 13 bits are for the subnets IDs (I can tell it by telling this IP is class B, therefor require 16 bits for the net ID and the rest of the mask (13) used for the subnets.) What I do if i get in the cmd the next IP:  __10 . 115 . 51 . 68 / 29__ Then, I couldnt really tell you how many bits are for the net and how many for the subnets...

Comment: Forget about the "class" nonsense. It's unhelpful for this. It's a silly concept that's in very introductory books. It's network vs. hosts. The subnet is a network. Sometimes you call the subnet a subnet, sometimes a subnet is the network (e.g. Azure). The point is how many bits are on the right; these can be used for hosts or most subnetting.